# ¿Como retornar un tipo de dato por "Referencia"?

Tags: java

Al momento de ejecutar no me muestra ningun `Bajo`. Quisiera saber cómo hago para retornar el elemento.

Adjunto código.

```
public Bajo buscar(String nombre, String referencia){
    Bajo respuesta= null;
    for(int i=0;i< bajos.size();i++){
        Bajo actual=(Bajo) bajos.get(i);
        if(actual.darNombre().equals(nombre) 
                && actual.darReferencia().equals(referencia)){
            respuesta= actual;
        }
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que muestras debería funcionar sin problemas. Quizás lo que quieres es mostrar el contenido del elemento. Si estás en una aplicación en consola, conviene utilizar `System.out.println`:

```
Bajo bajo = buscar("nombre", "referencia");
if (bajo != null) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Este es un bajo %s con referencia %s", bajo.darNombre(), bajo.darReferencia()));
}
```

Si lo que quieres es imprimir directamente utilizando la variable devuelta, debes sobre escribir el método `toString` en la clase `Bajo`:

```
public class Bajo {
    /* definición actual */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Bajo. Nombre: %s. Referencia: %s",
                darNombre(), darReferencia());
    }
}
```

Y el código anterior se escribiría:

```
Bajo bajo = buscar("nombre", "referencia");
if (bajo != null) {
    System.out.println(bajo);
}
```

---

Si bien es cierto que el código funciona, puedes aprovechar los beneficios de la interfaz `List` y convertir ese `for` en un `for` mejorado que se asemeja a `for-each` de otros lenguajes:

```
public Bajo buscar(String nombre, String referencia){
    Bajo respuesta= null;
    //for(int i=0;i< bajos.size();i++){
    //    Bajo actual=(Bajo) bajos.get(i);
    //la línea de abajo reemplaza a las líneas anteriores
    //y es más eficiente puesto que utiliza un Iterator
    //el método get(i) puede tomar más tiempo en algunas implementaciones
    for (Bajo actual : bajos) {
        if (actual.darNombre().equals(nombre)
                && actual.darReferencia().equals(referencia)) {
            respuesta = actual;
            break; //importante! detiene el ciclo for
        }
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio

Comment: Si esta respuesta te sirve, te recomiendo que la [aceptes](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/428/227) :)

Comment: Acabo de agregar contenido que puede ayudarte en el desarrollo de tu aplicación. Te recomiendo revisarlo